# What's the cause of "Application not installed" error?

Tags: installation, apk

So I just downloaded the nightly version of Firefox (ARMv6) apk and when I install, I get the following error message:-

[image: Application not installed]

This, isn't a very friendly message.. what could be the cause? How do I find out?

Logcat for this particular problem says:-

```
W/PackageParser(  137): Exception reading libxul.so in /data/app/vmdl70897.tmp
W/PackageParser(  137): java.io.IOException
W/PackageParser(  137):         at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:207)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:432)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:154)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarFileInputStream.read(JarFile.java:109)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadCertificates(PackageParser.java:338)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCertificates(PackageParser.java:508)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.installPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:5906)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.access$2100(PackageManagerService.java:134)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService$5.run(PackageManagerService.java:4764)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
W/PackageParser(  137): Caused by: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: data error    
W/PackageParser(  137):         at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateImpl(Native Method)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:255)
W/PackageParser(  137):         at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:188)
W/PackageParser(  137):         ... 12 more    
E/PackageParser(  137): Package org.mozilla.fennec has no certificates at entry libxul.so; ignoring!
```

Although I've encountered this on the Firefox APK, I'd prefer a more general answer on how to fix or know the cause of such "Application not installed" problem.

Comment: Have you uninstalled existing Firefox app, in case you had it?

Comment: @SurajBajaj I never had firefox app installed. Never tried it.. (because firefox only recently released ARMv6 builds)

Comment: I am not sure how much it can help but still have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/application-not-installed-error-on-android)?

Comment: Do you have enough free space? Did you check logcat? What device do you have?

Comment: @LieRyan I have around 40 MB of free space on internal memory. The apk is just around 21 MB. Device is huawei IDEOS u8150 running froyo. Logcat attached.

Comment: @SurajBajaj that question had a lot of developer oriented responses and it didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: May be you want to try FF normal version. See if the problem exists. If not, this is a bug of the app. And if yes, there is a problem with your handset.

Comment: @Sid There are many different versions of Firefox.. the recent 'stable' ones are ARMv7 and won't be supported in mine.

Comment: @Power-Inside Have you tried re-downloading the APK? May the APK is corrupt. Again a wild guess...

Comment: @SurajBajaj It's ~20 MB.. part of why I'm reluctant in retrying it.. anyway a new nightly might be out.. so I'd try that one..

Comment: I've seen this happening when I tried installing an APK a second time while the first one is still running on the background. The second installation would fail with "Application not installed" although the application will still end up installed and runs fine. It's probably a different issue than the one you're having though.

Comment: Application not compatible with your Android version? BTW What version of Android are you running?

Comment: @t0mm13b Android 2.2

Comment: Try to reinstall *Firefox* **and** *Nightly*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exceptions coming from zip (in the log extract) indicate that the package is corrupt. This error could have been introduced by the download, or when the package file was generated. You could check for download errors by verifying the APK file's SHA-1 or MD5 checksum against a checksum provided by the download site. Obviously each site will have a different way of telling you the checksum. Also, the method of verifying it is different depending on what OS your PC runs: on Linux it's as simple as running `md5sum file` or `sha1sum file`.

Note that this won't always be the case from the "Application not installed" error message. As others have indicated, that message usually results from trying to install a package that already exists on the system, unless the new package has a newer version number and is signed by the same key.

Comment: Well it did seem like a corrupted download. There was no checksum for me to compare with and I even tried restarting the download and completing it multiple times over and over.. seems like the server had hosted a bad APK. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete app's files in **/data/data/package-name** and **/data/dalvik-cache/package-name** (You need root access to do that).
That fixed an issue with app that **has been broken** on my system and has *error code -2* in **logcat**.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would fix the issue since the error happened on the *first* install so those files were not present.