# "This app is not compatible with your device" after APK install

Tags: installation, apk

I tried to download an APK from the web because the App is no longer available in the Play Store and the App is vital for my 360° cam.

It worked fine on my Huawei P20 Pro (Android/EMUI 12), but I switched to a Google Pixel 7 Pro (Android 13) and now I am not able to install the APK.

Is there a workaround for installing the APK, even though the message pops out "This App is not compatible with your device"?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. The package installer app rarely tells the exact error message. Could you [get the log](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) when installing the APK ([example post](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35840/44325))?